# next instruction to check if the input is a vowel?i have included the snippet

Tags: python

i want to know how a list referenced in python using for loop. In the snippet below if j points to 'a'initially and then proceeds until 'u' ,then what should be the next instruction to check if the input is a vowel?

```
name = input(" ")
c = ['a','e','i','o','u']
for j in c
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, you need to show more effort here as this snippet doesn't attempt anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check your test easily simply using string, which is also a special collection in python:

```
if name in "aeiou":
    # logic
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is list you have to refer the list:

```
if name in c:
    #some logic logic
```